# Array of generic holders

Tags: java, arrays, generics

If I have a map of Entry .. objects , and I have an array in a class

```
private Entry<K,V> array;
```

Can I say

```
array = new Entry[someInt];
```

which I've done, or do I need a typecast like my instructor says is necessary such as

```
array = (Entry<K,V> E[]) new Entry[someInt];
```

Note that the first one did work when I ran my JUnits.

Comment: Why would you edit back to code formatting changes I made?? Your code has angle brackets in it

Comment: The first solution is bad practice, the second has a typo: `array = (Entry<K,V>[]) new Entry[someInt];`

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about doing a List ?

```
Entry<K,V> array = new ArrayList<Entry<K,V>>();
array.add(new HashMap<K,V>());
```

Comment: I have to use a backingArray, but I'm just wondering if the casting is really necessary

Comment: Oh, gotcha. When using Java collection framework classes java e.g. ArrayList, LinkedList or HashSet etc. They accept an object of type java.lang.Object, which allows insertion of any object into collection. When we retrieve Object from the collection they are of type java.lang.Object which needs to be cast on respective for performing the operation. I dont have your entire code in front of me, so i cant tell you if we can do the declaration without getting a Class Cast Exception .

Comment: We are basically implementing our own hashMap. And the first way gives me no exceptions and runs fine, but my professor says it's an issue.

Comment: array = new Entry[someInt], would just create a array of the class objects. You are basically creating a class with two generics, and generics have restrictions. Now that could be a problem or not depending on how the rest of the code is written. I would just add the typecast if your professor wants it, and you can ask him why he specifically is asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either one. Implicit conversions to and from raw types are allowed without a cast.

`array = new Entry[someInt];` will produce an unchecked conversion warning.

`array = (Entry<K,V>[])new Entry[someInt];` will produce an unchecked cast warning.

So neither one is really better than the other.

Note that if you create the array with the wildcard type, you will need to have a cast:

```
array = (Entry<K,V>[])new Entry<?,?>[someInt]; // compiles
array = new Entry<?,?>[someInt];               // doesn't compile
```